# Получить ключ зная position элемента в LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android

Вообщем,необходимо из этой коллекции

```
 Map<String, Integer> imageCountru = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

получить position. В коллекции хранятся ссылки на файл такого рода:
**String england = "http://test.com";** (key) а value изображения(r.drawable.test),
не получается получить и передать элемент сюда
**URL url = new URL(    );**
Пробую получить элемент:

```
publick int position;
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final int resId = mData.get(position).getResId();

        holder.getItemImageView().setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(resId));
        holder.getItemImageView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                position = holder.getPosition();

                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                  //toast
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

В классе main есть метод в котором нужно получать вбыранный элемент и его скачивать,т.е передать 
к приvеру выбранную ссылку **String england = "http://test.com";**  в **new URL(    );**

Comment: imageCountru.entrySet().forEach(data -> { data.getKey(); data.getValue()});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` не поддерживает доступ по индексу, да и вообще любые стандартные мапы не поддерживают.

Самое простое - создавать `ArrayList` или преобразовывать к массиву и обращаться по индексу:

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>(map.keys());
map.keys().toArray()[index] //1
list.get(index); //2
```

Это конечно не очень эффективно, потому что происходит итерация по всем ключам.

Если важна производительность, можно написать свою мапу, что-то вроде этого(набросал, не тестил):

```
public class IndexedLinkedHashMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {

    private final ArrayList<K> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V previous = super.put(key, value);
        if (previous == null)
            arrayList.add(key);
        return previous;
    }

    public K getKeyByIndex(int index) {
        return arrayList.get(index);
    }
}
```

Или взять готовое из апач коммонс [LinkedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LinkedMap.html)